# i have no app/build/generated/source/navigation-args folder

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle, android-navigation

i'm trying to make a simple room library app by using ([Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rfBU75sguk&list=PLSrm9z4zp4mEPOfZNV9O-crOhoMa0G2-o&index=4&ab_channel=Stevdza-San)). But i have no autogenerated class "ListFragmentDirections" (6:00 min in tutorial). I started looking for it and find that i should be in app/build/generated/source/navigation-args/debug package, but I don't have it. I think it's becouse my gradle

gradle

````
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.coursework'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.coursework"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            def nav_version = "2.7.6"
            classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    // Navigation Component
    def navigation_ver = "2.7.6"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_ver"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_ver"

    // Room components
    def room_ver = "2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_ver"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_ver"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_ver"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_ver"

    // Lifecycle components
    def lifecycle_ver = "2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_ver"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_ver"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_ver"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5"
}```


i tryed to ask chat gpt, but it goesn't help
````

Comment: did you removed the already generated code? If not do it and rebuilt

Comment: @writer_chris doesn't helped

Comment: you can also try 'invalidate caches...'. File>invalide caches... Do you use the right room version? The vid is 3 years old and plays in the xml world. I'm not sure if older version would work better? Alot changed since jetpack compose